# Error trying to retrieve description field from AD

Tags: sql, vba, active-directory

I'm trying to get the data from AD users to automatically fill in the data of my users in an Access database, for that I'm using the following query to get the data I need

```
    strADQuery = "<LDAP://" & strDefaultNamingContext & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));samAccountName,displayName,mail,telephoneNumber,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,description;subtree"
```

The idea is to get each of those values and store them in a Users table. Before I do that I'm just printing the data on the screen to verify the query is working properly. It works for every field except for the description field, which is throwing a runtime error 13, types do not match. The 'value' variable shows its variant/string for the rest of the fields, and a variant/variant for the description field, so how do I get to read it and store it to my table?

Edit:
Ok, a little update. Each Field has a Value variable of the String (variant/string) type. For the 'description' Field though, the Value variable is of the Variant (variant/variant) type containing a string (variant/string) variable also named Value. I've tried directly printing it as well as converting it to a string with CStr and then printing the string. In both cases I get the following errors:

- If I try to print or convert results.Fields("Description") -> Error
  13 Types don't match. That's what's working for the rest of the
  fields.
- If I try to print or convert
  results.Fields("Description").Value - > Error 13 Types don't match.
- If I try to print or convert
  results.Fields("Description").Value.Value -> Error, an object is
  required.

How can I access that second Value variable that contains the string I need?

Thanks!

Comment: Description is a multivalued attribute, which is why you can't convert it to a string. Try assigning "description" to a variant array and looping through it. `Dim varr As Variant Dim desc as Variant ...  varr = results.Fields("Description")  For Each desc in varr` etc. See also, this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7026e0b3-c20d-4e19-a017-926a23df60d7/sql-server-2005-active-directory-query?forum=sqlreportingservices